# React.js Using axios to send integer data but get [object object] in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send an integer to the backend to perform some calculations using `axios` in `React`. However, In the backend, I got `[object object]` instead. I tried to see what is in the object by doing `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body))` and it returns empty object

I am using body parser as well. My other route is using axios to send data(object), it worked fine. Is integer not regard as the pure integer in body.parse?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/buy', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("wallet");
    var myquery = { amount: {$gt: 0} }
    console.log("New Amount:" + req.body)
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body))
    var newquery = { $set: {amount: req.body}}
    /*dbo.collection("account").updateOne(myquery, newquery, function(err, re) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Wallet updated")
      db.close();
    });*/
  });
});
```

My react:

```
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var remain = this.state.wallet - this.state.total
    console.log(remain)

    axios({ method: 'post', url: '/buy', data: remain})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In generally also numbers, boolean, strings and null without any object or array around are valid json. But `axios` does not treat those as JSON by default in its auto detection process, only those with `typeof` being equal to `object` will be send with the content type `application/json`.

You would need to set the `content-type` header yourself:

```
axios({ method: 'post', url: '/buy', data: 1, headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}})
```

Now axios would send with the *"correct"*  content type header so that the receiver will treat it as JSON.

But now the `body-parser` would complain about the received data not beeing valid json. That's because of the following option:

> **strict**
>    When set to `true`, will only accept arrays and objects; when `false` will accept anything `JSON.parse` accepts. Defaults to `true`.

Your code would work using the option `strict: false` for `body-parser` in combination with the `Content-Type` header settings for `axios`.

So it is possible to get it work, but the easiest way would be wrapping the integer into an object.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by putting the number into an object like so:

```
axios({ method: 'post', url: '/buy', data: { amount : remain}})
```

Now it is sending the correct information. Any explanation on why it was causing error is appreciated

Comment: Yea, data must be type of an object, { }.

Answer (score -1):

You are concatenating the object with a string in your console log:

```
console.log("New Amount:" + req.body)
```

Try this instead:

```
console.log("New Amount:", req.body)
```

Comment: the printing is not the problem. I changed to the new console.log and I get  `New Amount: {}` which is an empty object

Answer (score -1):

Since you access the request body using req.body.something. The data attribute must be an object type, {}.
Like this,

```
data: { remain }
```

So you can access from the server using

```
req.body.remain
```

Comment: You can access the whole body using `req.body` body would hold a number, string, boolean, null,  object or array as its content. The `body-parse` module by default only accpets `[]` or `{}` even so the others are also valid JSON. With `strict: false` it would accept all of them. And to get axios to send the `json` content type header you have to set it manually. Using `data: { remain }` is one way to solve it, but its not a requirement.